# Memcpy - assigning values to block of data

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a large block of memory and I am passing bits of this memory to these functions:

```
void setBlockSize(char* node, int size) {
    printf("need size: %i\n",size);
    memcpy(node, (void *)&size, sizeof(size));
    printf("set to: %i\n",node); 
}

//written for 4 byte pointer, 32 bit addressing
void setNextPointer(char* node, char* next){
    printf("need ptr: %p\n", next);
    memcpy((node+4), (void*)&next, sizeof(next));
    printf("next: %p, set: %p\n",next, (void*)(node+4));
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
need size: 8296
set to: 137666560
need ptr: (nil)
next: (nil), set: 0x834a004
need size: 137666456
set to: 137666560
need ptr: 0xffee4874
next: 0xffee4874, set: 0x834a004
need size: 104
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./mallocTest
```

It appears that the wrong values are being set (I am trying to set a pointer, and an integer. Is this not correct usage for memcpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first function, you are not dereferencing the pointer when you output the value you just wrote to.  Try this:

```
printf("set to: %i\n", *(int*)node);
```

Same problem is present in the second function.  You want to output the pointer value stored inside the pointer `node+4`, not `node+4` itself:

```
printf("next: %p, set: %p\n", next, *(void*)(node+4));
```

Just regarding `memcpy`, it's strange to use it for writing a single value.  You can avoid `memcpy` like this:

```
*(int*)node = size;
*(char**)(node+4) = next;
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `sizeof(int)` instead of `4`.  Maybe you should make a little struct to hold an `int` and pointer, and use those instead.

Comment: Wouldn't I be setting:
`*(char**)(node+4) = next`? as node+4 is being set as a char*

Comment: Oh yes that's right.  Sorry, I didn't pick up your edit until just now.